# Handler and interface runnable - which have new thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have read on stack this:

> When you use  new Handler().post(r) (or Message), you added the
>   Runnable object to Looper and execute the code later in the same
>   thread.

this answer is accepted.

So now I have a dilemma, some guys on my last interview give me tip: if you want to run something in other thread and update from this new thread UI, lets use a Handler.

So Handler is new thread or not ?
Or maybe runnable in this thread works on other thread ? 
Can somebody explain me ?

from official doc:

> There are two main uses for a Handler: (1) to schedule messages and
>   runnables to be executed at some point in the future; and (2) to
>   enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own.

Answer (score 2):

- `Handler` is not a new thread. It is just a mechanism to schedule some task to be done in the UI thread.
- Creating/Posting to a `Handler` does not create new thread.
- The `Runnable` posted to a `Handler` runs in the UI thread as soon as UI thread becomes free.

When you create a `Runnable` instance and post it, its reference gets stored and its `run` method will be called from the UI thread, at some point in the future. (You can also specify the delay using the method `postDelayed()`.)

Comment: from official doc: "There are two main uses for a Handler: (1) to schedule messages and runnables to be executed at some point in the future; and (2) to enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own."

Comment: could you explain 2 ?

Comment: Performing on different thread than your own – Suppose you are running something in a background thread and you want to run something else or pass the result in the UI thread, you will need to post a `Runnable`.

Answer (score 1):

A `Handler` is associated with a `Looper` (and that `Looper`'s thread). When you call [`new Handler()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#Handler()) to create a new handler you're associating it with the `Looper` for the current thread (the thread where the current code is running).

Once you have this object, you can use it from another thread to report results, etc.

So for example, from a background thread you can call [`post()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)) on a handler object that is associated with the UI thread. The `Runnable` you pass will be executed by that handler in its thread (not in the thread where the `post()` function was called) when the Handler gets to it.

For another source of info/details on loopers and handlers see https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui

Answer (score 1):

Here's the quote form [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler):

> A Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects associated with a thread's MessageQueue. Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue. When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it -- from that point on, it will deliver messages and runnables to that message queue and execute them as they come out of the message queue.
>
> There are two main uses for a Handler: (1) to schedule messages and runnables to be executed at some point in the future; and (2) to enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own.

This part is quite important:

**When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue of the thread that is creating it**

`Handler` is not a new thread and it can handle messages in a queue when you're passing new Runnables to the [`Looper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper) thread, which process them. Each message can be processed in a separate thread or thread pool, when you explicitly do it. Otherwise, it will be processed in the thread, where `Looper` was created (it can be main/UI thread or other thread).

I was also confused about this mechanism some time ago, collected some links, resources and wrote sample app using `Handler` and `Looper`. You can check it here: https://github.com/pwittchen/android-looper-sample. Maybe you'll find it useful.